# Не могу вывести последний элемент из MySQL базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Я вот пытаюсь вывести последний элемент из базы данных (по максимальному ID). У меня подключена библиотека RedBean, там есть команда `R::exec();`. В скобках записывается команда к БД MySQL (произвольная).
Так вот, в чем проблема, я ввожу команду `Select max('id') as 'maxid' from 'posts'` в скобки (`R::exec(Select max('id') as 'maxid' from 'posts');`) и оно мне выдаёт единицу. Я ввожу тот же запрос, но уже в интерфейсе PhpMyAdmin, и оно мне выдаёт "11" - максимальный ID.
Обрыл наверное пол-интернета - найти решения не могу.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скажите, а где вы изучаете RedBean, на каких курсах?

Comment: exec применяется только для обновления БД, он не может ничего вернуть из запроса. Посмотрите в документации https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying другие функции, например getRow

Comment: `max('id')` - у вас проблемы, вы везде используете одинарные кавычки, а это недопустимо в принципе, нужно использовать тильду \`. Или вы это поправили за счет того, чтобы не ломалось выделение ? Если да, то для оформления кода, нужно использовать `4 пробела` или экранировать тильды слешем \.

Comment: @And Это бэктик. Тильда - это `~`.

Comment: @Akina, тьфу, перепутал, апостофы.